# Performance on aggregate over 10mio records slow in Postgres

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, performance

I'm trying to find out, why a simple aggregate query performs really slow on Postgres 15 from my point of view.

I have a growing data table with 10 mio records of sensor data

```
CREATE TABLE public.ts_number (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    ts int8 NOT NULL,
    val float4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT ts_number_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id, ts)
);
CREATE INDEX ts_number_id_idx ON public.ts_number USING btree (id, ts, val);
```

I want to aggregate all data into 1-minute interval and join it with the sensor name from another table. But I'm wondering why the basic aggregate has so big differences in execution speed? Timestamp is in milliseconds since UNIX epoch.

From my understanding, an additional index won't help? There are only about 1000 rows with val = NULL in the whole set of 10 mio records.

```
select
    date_trunc('minute', to_timestamp(tn.ts / 1000)) as "time",
    tn.id,
    round(avg(tn.val::numeric), 1) as value
from
    ts_number tn
where
    tn.val is not null
group by
    tn.id,
    date_trunc('minute', to_timestamp(tn.ts / 1000))
order by
    date_trunc('minute', to_timestamp(tn.ts / 1000));
```

I've tried different indexes and subqueries to narrow down but I cannot find the answer.

Execution plan for Postgres:

jit=off, track_io_timing=true

EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, TIMING)
`

```
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                              |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Sort  (cost=1438043.51..1448107.59 rows=4025633 width=44) (actual time=45605.997..46283.850 rows=3507690 loops=1)                       |
  Sort Key: (date_trunc('minute'::text, to_timestamp(((ts / 1000))::double precision)))                                                 |
  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 92136kB                                                                                            |
  Buffers: shared hit=32 read=79640, temp read=56259 written=100732                                                                     |
  I/O Timings: shared/local read=12067.837, temp read=1178.562 write=3915.268                                                           |
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=707851.61..923882.68 rows=4025633 width=44) (actual time=29691.221..42565.892 rows=3507690 loops=1)          |
        Group Key: date_trunc('minute'::text, to_timestamp(((ts / 1000))::double precision)), id                                        |
        Planned Partitions: 32  Batches: 33  Memory Usage: 33041kB  Disk Usage: 368648kB                                                |
        Buffers: shared hit=32 read=79640, temp read=44742 written=89197                                                                |
        I/O Timings: shared/local read=12067.837, temp read=1147.856 write=3727.306                                                     |
        ->  Seq Scan on ts_number tn  (cost=0.00..295394.36 rows=10785399 width=16) (actual time=6.016..18958.130 rows=10785155 loops=1)|
              Filter: (val IS NOT NULL)                                                                                                 |
              Rows Removed by Filter: 1073                                                                                              |
              Buffers: shared hit=32 read=79640                                                                                         |
              I/O Timings: shared/local read=12067.837                                                                                  |
Planning Time: 0.289 ms                                                                                                                 |
Execution Time: 46617.899 ms                                                                                                            |
```

`

pg_tune settings:
`

```
# DB Version: 15
# OS Type: linux
# DB Type: dw
# Total Memory (RAM): 4 GB
# CPUs num: 4
# Connections num: 25
# Data Storage: ssd

max_connections = 25
shared_buffers = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 3GB
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 500
random_page_cost = 1.1
effective_io_concurrency = 200
work_mem = 10485kB
min_wal_size = 4GB
max_wal_size = 16GB
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 4
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 2
```

`

Host is a J4125 quad core with 8GB RAM and 1TB SSD running Proxmox. Proxmox runs in its own container (plain debian bullseye) with virtual resources: 4 cores, 4GB RAM, 2GB SWAP. No others containers are currently active.

Updated results:

Added calculated column

`ts_time timestamp generated always as (date_trunc('minute', timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + make_interval(secs => ts/1000))) stored`

and filled it with

```
update ts_number
set ts_time = date_trunc('minute', timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + make_interval(secs => ts/1000));
```

then created a new index

```
create index on ts_number(ts_time, id) 
  include (val)
where val is not null;
```

then EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS, TIMING)

````
QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                                                 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=260210.24..262870.90 rows=10200 width=20) (actual time=28025.740..34159.907 rows=3507690 loops=1)                           |
  Group Key: ts_time, id                                                                                                                                   |
  Buffers: shared hit=86581 read=93231, temp read=31437 written=32171                                                                                      |
  I/O Timings: shared/local read=46057.413, temp read=121.378 write=1017.921                                                                               |
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=260210.24..262590.40 rows=20400 width=44) (actual time=28025.718..31512.629 rows=3738515 loops=1)                                |
        Workers Planned: 2                                                                                                                                 |
        Workers Launched: 2                                                                                                                                |
        Buffers: shared hit=86581 read=93231, temp read=31437 written=32171                                                                                |
        I/O Timings: shared/local read=46057.413, temp read=121.378 write=1017.921                                                                         |
        ->  Sort  (cost=259210.21..259235.71 rows=10200 width=44) (actual time=23712.198..24001.505 rows=1246172 loops=3)                                  |
              Sort Key: ts_time, id                                                                                                                        |
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 90712kB                                                                                                   |
              Buffers: shared hit=86581 read=93231, temp read=31437 written=32171                                                                          |
              I/O Timings: shared/local read=46057.413, temp read=121.378 write=1017.921                                                                   |
              Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 78008kB                                                                                        |
              Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 76384kB                                                                                        |
              ->  Partial HashAggregate  (cost=258429.08..258531.08 rows=10200 width=44) (actual time=20173.138..21185.291 rows=1246172 loops=3)           |
                    Group Key: ts_time, id                                                                                                                 |
                    Batches: 5  Memory Usage: 262193kB  Disk Usage: 7536kB                                                                                 |
                    Buffers: shared hit=86553 read=93231, temp read=799 written=1530                                                                       |
                    I/O Timings: shared/local read=46057.413, temp read=3.658 write=34.272                                                                 |
                    Worker 0:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 237585kB                                                                                          |
                    Worker 1:  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 237585kB                                                                                          |
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on ts_number tn  (cost=0.00..224726.62 rows=4493662 width=16) (actual time=2.821..16943.198 rows=3595052 loops=3)|
                          Filter: (val IS NOT NULL)                                                                                                        |
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 358                                                                                                      |
                          Buffers: shared hit=86553 read=93231                                                                                             |
                          I/O Timings: shared/local read=46057.413                                                                                         |
Planning:                                                                                                                                                  |
  Buffers: shared hit=25                                                                                                                                   |
Planning Time: 22.619 ms                                                                                                                                   |
Execution Time: 34999.933 ms                                                                                                                               |```
````

Comment: Please decide on one database you want to optimize: Postgres or MariaDB. If you really need it for both, ask one question for each DBMS. Performance tuning is highly DBMS specific and an answer for Postgres will most probably not help for MySQL and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to go with Postgres in the future but I want to understand why the query times differ so much on the different DBMS. I think I'm doing something wrong but don't know what.

Comment: Please add the execution plan in SQL Server and for PostgreSQL. That will shed light on the issue.

Comment: Also, does the SQL Server table have a clusterd primary key, or just an unique constraint?

Comment: See the execution plans above in my question (added them). On all three RDBMS the only index is the primary key (id, tn), nonclustered

Comment: The SQL Server one does have a Parallelism operator. What degree of Parallelism does it run at when taking 6s? The query is not currently written in a way that any of them will take advantage of the fact that an index on  `id, ts` will also provide an ordering that could be used for grouping (though the index would also need to be able to supply the `val` column anyway)

Comment: postgres is able to run [parallel queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-query.html) while your query plan has no one. I reproduced your table with 10 mio rows in my pg db and the same query takes 12 sec to 19 sec with 4 // workers and no further optimization.

Comment: For Postgres: 1) Have you run [Analyze](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) on the table? 2) Try the the query with `jit` turned off: `set jit = off;`
`

Comment: Added an composite index (id, ts, val) with now effect. From my understanding, the table must be read anyway to calculate the average?

I've increased workers from 2 to 4 without no effect on execution time. EXPLAIN also doesn't show any gather

Comment: What unit is "mio"?

Comment: Just reading the data from disk in PostgreSQL took more time than the entire operation in SQL Server.  I would say that your attempt to give them the same resources has failed.  I think you will need to give us more details on what virtualization system you are using what those resource assignments look like.

Comment: You should turn off `jit` as Adrian has suggested. Please also change `track_io_timing` to true, then run `explain (analyze, buffers, timing)` so that we can see how much time was really spent for I/O but I share jjanes suspicion: your hardware doesn't match. You could shave off some more runtime by increasing `work_mem` so that the final sort stop doesn't need to be done on disk

Comment: On reason for the poor Postgres performance is the casting of `val` to numeric. Using `avg(ts.val)` seems to be substantially faster on Postgres (and is equivalent to the code you use for SQL Server). With a generated column that computes the "rounded" timestamp and an index including that column I get this down to 4 seconds on a 8 year old desktop with a spinning harddisk: https://explain.depesz.com/s/HLhZ

Comment: I've added the requested information to the question, hope you can give me more insights.
I must cast avg(ts.val) to numeric, otherwise round() will fail. In the query plan I see, that the timestamp is casted to double precision. Another pitfall?
BTW: Thank you all very much for your support! :)

Comment: See the first comment to this question and make the necessary edits. I suggest focussing this one on PostgreSQL as that seems to be the general direction of the comments

Comment: You did not use `round()` with the SQL Server query, so why use it with Postgres. But casting the average will be faster than casting each value: e.g. `round(avg(tn.val)::numeric, 1)` is substantially faster on my computer than `round(avg(tn.val::numeric), )` because the latter casts each and every value, whereas the former only needs to do the cast once.

Comment: 19 seconds for the seq scan seems quite slow. This takes about 3.5 seconds with my spinning harddisk. Seems the I/O system of your computer (or virtual machine?) is quite slow.

Comment: Didn't make disk benchmarks but a simple dd gives about 460mb/s read and 200mb/s write over a 10gb test file.
The table size is about 1.6gb (incl. indexes)

Comment: @AndiDepressivum - If you provide the XML for the actual execution plan from SQL Server this will provide some information that will help in the comparison. You can paste that here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/. It will show things like available memory, per operator timings, number of pages read from disc from the read ahead mechanism, degree of parallelism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The index on all three columns isn't going to help as your query can't make use of it.

Casting the average to be able to round it, rather then casting every value should already make a difference, i.e. `round(avg(tn.val)::numeric, 1)` instead of `round(avg(tn.val::numeric), 1)`

---

However the query still needs the costly hash aggregate and sorting (and with your extremely small work_mem this is spilling to your apparently slow disk).

One way to avoid that, is to support this using an index. Building the index is easier if you do the conversion from the unix epoch to a proper timestamp using a generated column (which might be helpful in other situations as well):

```
create table ts_number 
(
  id bigint, 
  ts bigint, 
  val double precision, 
  ts_time timestamp generated always as (timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + make_interval(secs => ts)) stored,
  primary key (id, ts)
);
```

The somewhat strange looking expression for the generated column is necessary because using `to_timestamp()` is not an immutable function and thus can't be used in a generated column (or index).

Then you can create such an index:

```
create index on ts_number(date_trunc('minute', ts_time), id) 
   include (val)
where val is not null; --<< won't make a big difference but doesn't hurt either
```

Which leads to this query:

```
select date_trunc('minute', ts_time),
       tn.id,
       avg(tn.val) as value
from ts_number tn
where  tn.val is not null
group by tn.id, date_trunc('minute', ts_time)
order by date_trunc('minute', ts_time);
```

This should already be faster than your original query. If you **always** aggregate on "minute level" you could already do that in the generated column:

```
create table ts_number 
(
  id bigint, 
  ts bigint, 
  val double precision, 
  ts_time timestamp generated always as (date_trunc('minute', timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' + make_interval(secs => ts))) stored,
  primary key (id, ts)
);
```

which then leads to the simplified index:

```
create index on ts_number(ts_time, id) 
  include (val)
where val is not null;
```

and the simplified query:

```
select ts_time,
       tn.id,
       avg(tn.val) as value
from ts_number tn
where  tn.val is not null
group by tn.id, ts_time
order by ts_time;
```

This brought down the runtime from initially ~45 seconds to ~5 seconds on my old laptop with a spinning harddisk.

This kind of table is one of the rare cases where PostgreSQL's lack of "index organized tables" (aka "clustered index" in SQL Server) is indeed a disadvantage because the index to support this kind of queries needlessly duplicates the storage (index + table).

---

Note that a `work_mem` of only 10MB is way too small if you are serious about doing larger aggregations with Postgres.

I don't really know if your SQL Server installation is also that severely limited with regards to the memory it can use for grouping and hashing, but given the numbers I'd suspect it can use substantially more memory.

Comment: Beside that I want to stay with Postgres, the SQL Server runs in a container with exactly the same resources. Therefore I didn't understand what's going wrong.
I'll try your hints - a good way to learn more about Postgres & usage. 
What size of work mem do you suggest? There's only one connection feeding new data in and the connection for querying the data for analytics.
PS: Thank you very much!

Comment: The ideal work_mem depends on which query you end up with. Your original query probably needs > 500MB to get rid of the disk sort and speed up aggregation. My final query doesn't need much work_mem as the index is already pre-sorted, so it should work fine with 30-50MB. But you need to test that with the low-end computer you are using.

Comment: Updated my question with the results, only got a reduction by half the time. Work_mem increased to 128MB. Still a lot of slow disk I/O where I still clueless why this happens.

Comment: With such a low-end server you will never get acceptable performance. You probably wouldn't even buy a smartphone with those specs today.

Comment: Interestingly, SQL Server is performing much more better with the same resources. So the hardware cannot be the only bottleneck, otherwise other containers on other hosts with the same spec would suffer. If a columnstore index is the key, I should better stick with SQL Server, MariaDB or try Citus? Even with materialized views the pre-aggregated dataset would grow.

Comment: No idea. Maybe SQL Server uses memory differently or the defaults are less conservative.

Comment: Maybe I find it out next year. Anyway, thank you very much for your support which gives me a lot of hints to prevent bottlenecks by design. Truncating the timestamp during write is quite smart and I think I can offload the rest with materialized views in the background.

Comment: work_mem and shared_buffers were the key to success. Increased shared_buffers to 2GB as the container limit is 4GB (without the host's buffer cache) and work_mem to '512MB'. Execution time for the optimized query is now below 1s (after cold start of postgres)

Answer (score -12):

**Comparisons between a professional tool that required billions of dollars of investment (SQL Server) and do-it-yourself DBMSs are generally out of proportion.** This is why companies pay dearly for professional tools...

In this case the reasons why there are such differences are based on the following facts:

1. **parallelism**: SQL Server does automatic parallelism and can use several threads to calculate an aggregate. Neither MySQL nor PostgreSQL are able to do this.
2. **MVCC**: SQL Server keeps the number of "alive" rows in the page header. So it doesn't need to iterate through all the rows of a table to compute the aggregate. Other RDBMS, due to MVCC (optimistic locking) must scans all rows to distinguish between phantom rows and alive rows into pages, which cost a lot
3. **optimizer**: Microsoft has been investing massively in research and development for more than 30 years and its optimizer is currently far ahead of even Oracle... The level of optimization of MySQL / PostgreSQL is barely higher than what the first RDBMS of the 80 years
4. **compression**: SQL Server makes it possible to compress the data without having to decompress them to exploit them logically. This doesn't exist in MySQL or PostgreSQL
5. **columnar**: it is possible to use vertical indexes (columnstore in SQL Server terminology) to go even faster to calculate aggregates in SQL Server. This is obviously not possible in MySQL or PostgreSQL.

There would still be a lot of other things to say on these subjects, and I'll let you take a look at the [article I wrote and which compares PostgreSQL and SQL Server on this subject](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-2-count-performances/), we note discrepancies going as far as to more than 1000!

Comment: Thanks, that are some interesting facts I simply didn't think about on such a "simple" query.  Will spend some time and read your interesting research articles!

Comment: By the facts, when release 2005 of SQL Server was made by Microsoft there was almost 2000 persons inside the company that code the engine for almost 5 years... and about 10000 additionnal persons all aver the world that participate to the project outside MS like translators...

Comment: By the way... Do not use UNIXTIME. This is not a valid time (it's only a duration) it as many troubles and will cause a bug in some years....

Comment: I know, but the source system for data writes its timestamp as ms since UNIX epoch.

Comment: @Georg_Richter someone is lying... Probably Wikipedia that says https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server that MS SQL Server version begin with version 4.21a for Windows NT in 1993... So between 1993 an 2023 there is 30 years...

Comment: Postgres absolutely does parallel query. The optimizer does not have much to do on such a simple query, so this point is irrelevant here. There are columnstore options in Postgres - one of the most popular ones is even provided by microSoft.

Comment: Compression should be irrelevant for this type of query. Unless sql serVer's de-duplication of values on page level (which I assume you refer to with "logically") is also done for numeric values (but I doubt that unix timestamps would "compress" substantially). Note that Postgres does automatic de-duplication in B-Tree indexes

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name timestamps should compress quite well. It just needs to record an "anchor" value for each page and store the data as an offset from that value (so instead of an 8 byte `bigint` this would likely be a 4 byte `int` for many cases) - irrelevant here anyway though as there is no indication the OP applied compression

Comment: @MartinSmith: all documentation I found about prefix compression was using strings. And I am unsure if page level de-duplication would be very effective for unix epochs as I doubt there are many equal ones on a single page.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - yeah actually the "value offset" scheme might only be used for [columnstore compression](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/273266/3690) rather than rowstore compression on thinking about it

Comment: From the comment of the questioner to the accepted answer the Postgres one now executes in sub second timing.